# Lost information when i change the layout orientation

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, orientation

I have an android application with bluetooth conection in java and when I change the layout orientation (I've created the layout-land folder) the layout changes properly, but the information that I have is lost, all the messages received are gone and when I try to send a message it crashes and it shows me this Exception like the connection was lost but it's still running:

```
D/AndroidRuntime(29591): Shutting down VM
08-01 10:13:04.499: W/dalvikvm(29591): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aac8578)
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2168)
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2552)
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:103)
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9229)
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2163)
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591):    ... 12 more
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591):    at com.example.bluetooth.cochee.BluetoothConexion.escribir(BluetoothConexion.java:350)
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591):    at com.example.bluetooth.cochee.AndroidTabsActivity.Comprobar5(AndroidTabsActivity.java:554)
08-01 10:13:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(29591):    ... 15 more
08-01 10:13:07.429: I/Process(29591): Sending signal. PID: 29591 SIG: 9
08-01 10:13:09.849: W/KeyCharacterMap(29760): Can't open keycharmap file
08-01 10:13:09.849: W/KeyCharacterMap(29760): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/clearpad.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65541.devname='clearpad'
08-01 10:13:09.849: W/KeyCharacterMap(29760): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activity is restarted each time you do an orientation change, so you need to save the state of the activity in its lifecycle methods:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 1):

After configuration changes your activity will be recreated, so must not to hold a link to activity (you have a memory leak). also you shoul save information before onDestroy (you should use onSafeConfigurationChanges method).

Answer (score 0):

You must save all your information in onPause() method and restore in onResume() each time when you change orientation. Because android recreate all activity.

Read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html